# Eigenvalues of density operator under quantum channel

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, decoherence

Consider a 2x2 density operator $\rho$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}$ (where $\lambda_{1}\geq\lambda_{2}$) evolving into a 4x4 density operator $\rho'$ (with eigenvalues $\lambda'_{1},\lambda'_{2},\lambda'_{3},\lambda'_{4}$ in non-ascending order) under a quantum channel,

$$\rho \to \rho'=\sum_{i} M_{i}\rho M^{\dagger}_{i}
\quad\text{where}\quad
\sum_{i}M^{\dagger}_{i}M_{i}=I.$$

I am interested in the upper bounds on the largest eigenvalue $\lambda'_{1}$ of the final density operator $\rho'$ in terms of the eigenvalues $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}$ of the initial density operator $\rho$. Intuitively, I think $\lambda'_{1}\leq \lambda_{1}$ must hold true, but I want to show this rigorously.

Since I am considering a physical evolution $\rho \to \rho'$, I believe that the von-Neumann entropy can only increase i.e $S(\rho')\geq S(\rho)$. Please correct me if am wrong on this.

However as I mentioned, I am interested in obtaining an upper bound on $\lambda'_{1}$ which seems hard to obtain from the entropy inequality. I would be grateful if someone can point me to some useful references on the spectral evolution of density operators under quantum channels or give any hints/directions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt you'll be able to get useful bounds without restricting the class of channels.

Consider the following quantum channel (for arbitrary dimension $d,n$):

$$ T:\mathbb{C}^{d\times d}\to \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}: \rho \mapsto \operatorname{tr}(\rho) \sigma $$

where $\sigma$ is any quantum state. Using the Choi-Jamiolkowski isomorphism, you can easily see that this is indeed a completely positive map and by construction, it is trace-preserving.

Clearly, the spectrum of $\sigma$ is completely independent of the spectrum of $\rho$.

---

Okay, so there is no way to have these inequalities for arbitrary channels. You ask now:

> Since I am considering a physical evolution $\rho\to \rho^{\prime}$, I believe that the von-Neumann entropy can only increase i.e $S(\rho)\to S(\rho^{\prime})$.

This is wrong. For instance, this would mean that you could never prepare pure ancillary states for a quantum computation (and you can do this at least to very good precision). It would also mean that most completely positive, trace-preserving maps would not be physical. But of course, there are large classes of processes in nature, where (local) entropy can only increase. These channels are in some sense very "dissipative".

That means that although they are not as physically all-encompassing as you ask, let's consider quantum channels with increasing entropy.

### **The case of equal input and output dimensions**

I'm talking about this case, because I actually know the answer and maybe my comments help you to find what you need.

It turns out that a channel if entropy increasing if and only if it is unital (and therefore doubly-stochastic). That unitality is necessary for an entropy increasing channel is clear here, because the maximally mixed state has maximal entropy. The other direction follows from the fact that relative entropy only decreases under doubly-stochastic maps.

In this case, [here](http://www.njohnston.ca/2009/06/unital-channel-eigenvalue-majorization/) is an answer to your question with the upshot:
For a unital quantum channel $T$, the decreasingly ordered spectrum of $T(\rho)$ is majorized by the ordered spectrum of $\rho$ or put differently

$$ \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i^{\downarrow}(T(\rho))\leq \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i^{\downarrow}(\rho) \qquad \forall k=1,\ldots,n $$

This entails your inequality for this case, but it seems you are more interested in general channels.

### **The case of larger output dimensions**

Unlike the first case, I have never worked with this case or seen it being used in your context, so this will only be a weak attempt at an answer.

A classification is not as straightforward, because I believe I can always embed a quantum channel $T:\mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}\to \mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}$ into a larger one, where I don't do anything on the other two dimensions and this would still be a (now nonunital) entropy increasing channel. Therefore, while unital maps should still be entropy decreasing, now the converse is definitely not true.

However, if we suppose the channel is not merely entropy-increasing, but *unital* as above, I think I can provide you with a proof of an even stronger statement - please check for mistakes, I haven't done these manipulations in a while:

**Proposition:** Let $T:\mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}\to \mathbb{C}^{4\times 4}$ be a doubly-stochastic quantum channel. Then $\lambda_1(T(\rho))+\lambda_2(T(\rho))\leq \lambda_1(\rho)$ [the eigenvalues are ordered decreasingly].

The proof uses the theorem for channels with equal in- and output dimensions. Consider any $\rho$ and denote the eigenvalues of $T(\rho)$ by $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_4$. In the basis, where $T$ is diagonal, we can decompose $\mathbb{C}^{4\times 4}=\mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}\otimes \mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}$ writing (in qubit notation):

$$ \sum_{i=1}^4 \lambda_i |i\rangle\langle i|=\lambda_1|0\rangle\langle 0|+\lambda_2|01\rangle\langle 01|+\lambda_3|10\rangle\langle 10|+\lambda_4|11\rangle\langle 11|$$

Till now, nothing has happened (just changing bases). Now, instead of considering the map $T$, we consider the map $\operatorname{tr}_2\circ T$, the composition of the map and the partial trace on the second subsystem. Since the partial trace is doubly-stochastic and CP, this composition is also doubly-stochastic and CP and our majorization criterion holds.

We have:

$$\operatorname{tr}_2(T(\rho))=(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)|0\rangle\langle 0|+(\lambda_3+\lambda_4)|1\rangle\langle 1|$$

and then, via the majorization criterion: $\lambda_1+\lambda_2\leq \lambda_1(\rho)$ if $\lambda_1(\rho)$ is the largest eigenvalue of the initial state $\rho$.

With similar reasoning, it should be possible to get a number of interesting inequalities for similar questions at least for unital maps. I have no idea how to proceed for non-unital maps. Likewise, I have no real idea whether these criteria will be sufficient (but you didn't ask that anyways).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am interested in the physical evolution of density operators which have the constraint that the Von-Neumann entropy cannot decrease. It is not obvious to me if the above map you mention indeed respects this constraint.

Comment: @Girish You should make those restrictions clear in your question.

Comment: @Girish So you're saying that Martin's map is not CP? (Could be, it's been a while since I've dealt with those.) In any case, specify clearly in your question which class of maps you're dealing with. Provide a well-posed mathematical problem, with the specifications up front and well labeled.

Comment: @Emilio Ok thanks. I have edited the problem to include more details. Also, I am not really sure about Martin's map since it seems to suggest that any dxd quantum state can evolve into any nxn quantum state.

Comment: @Girish Martin's map is perfectly CPTP. There is no statement saying that the entropy of a system coupled to a bath has to increase. (Just consider a cold bath and an initially warm system!)

Comment: @Girish Well, it can - that's a 'scrap and re-prepare' map. Whether you can set up a careful quantification of outside interference that that map runs foul of is another question.

Comment: @Martin Thank you for your detailed and helpful answer. I'll need to familiarize with the idea of majorization and work out the details for myself. I will get back to you on this thread.

Comment: @Girish: Sure, if any questions remain, please ask away! If you at some point need to go a bit deeper into majorization, there is a book by Michael Nielsen about it and I can also suggest the beautiful book "Matrix Analysis" by Bhatia.

Comment: @Martin Majorization was just the thing I needed. Also, the reference by Nielsen that you provided is very useful indeed. Thanks a lot for your spot-on answer.